# Drawer Layout With JSON How is it?

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'm triying to make a Drawer Layout works with JSON which gets data from database. How can i create this ? Is there any easy way to this. Thank you much for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all Android design rules insist you to not use dynamic navigation drawer.

But if still you wanna make drawer layout that catches data from an API then you would require to make a listview.
don't Use the Android Navigation Drawer template.
You need to make a custom navigation drawer for that using ListView or RecyclerView 
Then you will need to use Some network catching libraries like Retrofit or Volley to parse the data from the JSON API

You can learn more about it.Just google the phrase
"How to make a Recyceler View in Android"
"Android Working with Volley Json Parsing"
:)